# Where to keep the Dataflow and Cloud composer python code?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

It probably is a silly question. In my project we'll be using Dataflow and Cloud composer. For that I had asked permission to create a VM instance in the GCP project to keep the both the Dataflow and Cloud composer python program. But the client asked me the reason of creation of a VM instance and told me that you can execute the Dataflow without the VM instance.

Is that possible? If yes how to achieve it? Can anyone please explain it? It'll be really helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run Dataflow pipelines or manage Composer environments in you own computer once your [credentials are authenticated](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) and you have both the [Google SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) and [Dataflow Python library](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python#set-up-your-environment) installed. However, this depends on how you want to manage your resources. I prefer to use a VM instance to have all the resources I use in the cloud where it is easier to set up VPC networks including different services. Also, saving data from a VM instance into GCS buckets is usually faster than from an on-premise computer/server.

Comment: HI @Juan, Thank you for your answer! One more clarification I needed, can I keep the code in GCS buckets? Or there are any drawbacks in using GCS vs. VM? Sorry for asking basic questions but I'm new to GCP.

Comment: Hi, you can use GCS to store code or any other data (like datasets, pictures, etc...). As you will see, Composer uses a bucket to store the Python DAGs. If you want a service in GCP to store objects for long term I would say that GCS is the proper service. There are different kinds of storage depending on how frequently you need to access the data. The VMs are of course useful for developing, troubleshooting and testing your code.

Comment: You can find more information about GCS in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs)